# Compute % results of two SQL queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

I have two sql queries below. each query returns an **integer**. Please help me in writing a new sql query which computes `(query1-query2)*100/query1`

Comment: Can you show the query you have written so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is:

```
with q1 as (
      <query 1 here>
     ),
     q2 as (
      <query 2 here>
     )
select (q1.cw_va_df - q2.cw_va_df) * 100.0 / q1.cw_va_df
from q1 cross join q2
```